# Python Nested Loop explanation

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

I’m new to python coding and i dont understand why the nested for loop is only returning 0 1 2 for the firs Iteration.

Input:

```
x = 3
for i in range (x):
  for j in range (x):
    x = 2
    print (i, '',j)
```

Output:

```
0  0
0  1
0  2
1  0
1  1
2  0
2  1
```

Comment: you don't know what `x = 2` does?

Comment: Range counts from `0` up to but not including `x`, and you change `x` to be `2` in the `j` loop. In the second `i` loop onwards it will use `range(2)`

Answer (score 2):

`x` is changed *after* it's passed to `range` to make `range(3)`. You only see the effects of the change (i.e. `range(2)`) on the *next* loop.

Comment: After reading the question again, this may be the answer to a slightly different question, but I hope it's still useful.

Answer (score 2):

**The Concept behind Nested for Loops:**

Let us break this problem down (I am a beginner myself!)

```
x = 3
for i in range (x):
```

**Now the range function has 3 parts (start, stop, step)**

**start**: start from this number

**stop**: maximum value

**step**: increments by this value

when we say range(x); it **assumes x=3 as the stop/max value** of range. **The start value is by default taken as 0**, and the **step value is by default taken as 1**. So the range we get here is [0,1,2,3) {starts from 0 and stops at 3}
So the values that **'i'** can take are **0,1,and 2** because 3 is max of the range; it is not included in the values i and j can take.

So output until this point:

```
for i in range (x):
  for j in range (x):
```

(printing i and j separated by a whitespace)is:

```
0  0
0  1
0  2
```

0 is  printed  at the start and the loop is  iterated 2 more times.

(you are getting all zeroes printed first for i as the statement you have written sends an instruction to print all the values of j for one value in the outer/main for loop; because loop for j is nested inside the loop for i)

Now,  x= 2 means that from this point,  values **'j'**  can take are **0,1**. Hence the second part of the output:

```
1  0
1  1
```

Similarly, the the third part of the output is:

```
2  0
2  1
```

Hence the final output you get is:

```
0  0
0  1
0  2
1  0
1  1
2  0
2  1
```

Answer (score 0):

### Long version

- In the for statement "`for` *target* `in` *expression* `:`" the second part is  an iterable object.
- `range` is not a 'reserved' word; it is the name of a built-in type(class) witch is iterable

  *Note : The syntax highlighter cheats if it highlights `range` as a reserved word. It does this, because this is generally useful as `range` is mainly used in association with `for`. But this does not change  what range is. However, this can mislead you.*

  As a result of the above:

  - the correct typing is `range(x)` not `range (x)`
  - `range(x)` build an objet of type range and initialize it with `x`.

### Short answer

`x` is interpreted when it is passed to `range()`.

Code to print the range objects:

```
x = 3
range_i = range(x) 
print(f"i loop x: {x}, range(x):{range_i}")
for i in range_i:
    range_j = range(x) 
    print(f"j loop x: {x}, range(x):{range_j}")
    for j in range_j:
        x = 2
        print(i, ' ',j)
```

Output

```
i loop x: 3, range(x):range(0, 3)
j loop x: 3, range(x):range(0, 3)
0   0
0   1
0   2
j loop x: 2, range(x):range(0, 2)
1   0
1   1
j loop x: 2, range(x):range(0, 2)
2   0
2   1
```

### Rule of thumb

Unless you **really** know what you are doing, do not mess with the expression of the for statement.

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for x in lst:
    if x == 'b':
        lst.remove('a')
    print(x, end = ' ')
```

gives

```
a b d
```

And

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for x in lst:
    if x == 'd':
        lst.insert(0, 'z')
    print(x, end = ' ')
```

does not end and 'z' never appears:

```
a b c d d d d d d d d d d d d d ...
```

### Musing around

*Note : what follows is **NOT** recommended*

You can redefine range. *(The example below is a very simplified redefinition: it does not take in account the second version of range : `range(start, stop[, step]`) neither it cares for other `range` specifications)*

```
def range(n):
    i = 0
    while i <= n: # note the use of '<=' instead of '<'
        yield i
        i += 1
```

And now 'range' does not behave as it should.
Example:

```
for i in range(3):
    print(x, end = ' ')
```

gives:

```
0 1 2 3
```

Yes: 0..3 not 0..2 as the 'true' `range`.